# Is there a list of every fields of every SF standard object?

Tags: list, fields

Is there a list of every fields of every SF standard object ?

I know how to have each field of an object in different ways..

I'm sure it would be possible using code, but it's for a collegue of mine, he does not code and was wondering if there was an official SF paper listing each field !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All standard objects are listed in [Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm). Clicking on any object will give you a list of the standard fields for that object, including the API name, type, database properties (e.g. create, update, nillable, filterable, sortable, groupable).

Comment: Thanks ! I'll forward your answer to my collegue, and note my answer finished !

Comment: @sfdcfox is there any api or an object that exposes this data for programmatic consumption?

Comment: @metasync Yes, there are at least four APIs you can use: Metadata, Tooling, standard, and the User Interface APIs, most of which come in SOAP and REST flavors. These APIs can tell you which objects there are, their record types, page layouts, picklist options, data types, and more. You'll want to just check out the relevant documentation. If you have a specific project in mind, I'd be happy to suggest the API that you'll probably need.

Comment: We were looking for list of all standard objects/custom objects and its fields irrespective of if current user has access to that field or not (user would have metadata access to fetch metadata).

Comment: @metasync That'd be the metadata API. It will return all fields regardless of access. It does require admin-level permissions to use, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link for the Salesforce Field Reference Guide: 
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_field_names_reference.pdf

Comment: That link will become outdated every release, however. The latest version is located [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_field_names_reference.pdf), for now, but will be obsoleted for Spring 19...

Answer (score 1):

We were looking for list of all standard objects/fields and its type irrespective of if user has access to that field via profile/permset or not.

We couldn't find a api which provides this info so we end up scrapping the standards objects documentation pages and create this gsheet with list of objects/fields and its attributes like updatable or not.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdC6dkQLdLfV7jJUajeNwJ7Ccac69V_U_53JeaQw7Ig/edit#gid=381239370